# JAWS Screen Reader reads page title twice

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

I have a simple ASPX page like the one below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test JAWS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="divBody">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Simple ASPX page</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

While testing the page using JAWS, I noticed the page title was read twice (mostly in Firefox). In other browsers, like IE and Chrome, it gets read in a different way.

Has anyone had the same issue? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I've checked your code in IE11, Firefox 98 and Chrome 99 with JAWS 2022 and the speech behaviour for your test page is no different from other pages I've checked (e.g., example.com). JAWS will read the the page title a few times but I don't think that it has anything to do with your code.